# How to create shearing stress in a cylinder? Is torque there or not in this process?

Tags: elasticity, stress-strain

Let's say we have a cylinder and we apply equal and opposite forces on two opposite faces of cylinder along the surface such that net force is zero according to my book in this case there is shear stress on cylinder and consequently its top is shifted by some angle x. But isn't there a net torque on the cylinder shouldn't it rotate it or do both things happen.

Even if we have an external force say friction but how can it balance torque if its line of action is same as one of these forces ?

Comment: Without more information on context I assume they mean a cylinder that is in some way secured so it is not free to rotate.  Applying it to a free cylinder obviously isn't a ton of stress.

Comment: Even if we say that cylinder is fixed at bottom then why does it explicitly say that two forces are acting one at top one at bottom what was the nead of equal and opposite force at bottom then in first place if it is understood that cylinder is fixed ?

Comment: Good point.  The equal force at the bottom would be the equivalent of a support resisting the movement, so it doesn't really make a difference.

Comment: Yes it is all really confusing.

Comment: Also can we say because the bottom is fixed and a force is on the top due to the resulting torque net of the above force the body shifts and hence comes under shear strain ?

Comment: The whole body is under shear strain.

Comment: Yes. Sorry i mean what is cause of shear deformation.

Comment: The torque causes it...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55699/discussion-between-jmac-and-raghav-singal).

Comment: Okay can you refer a good book or some source for solid mechanics ?